# How to set a default selection for a slicer in power bi and estabilsh connection betwwen two slicers?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have slicer which is showing options to select a year, this field is not directly used in any of the graphs. How to set the current year to be selected in this dropdown.
And in another slicer, I have given the option for the date range, I want by default it should show the current date range as per the "year to view" slicer.
How to achieve this?
Please see the attachments for clarity.[image: first slicer]

[image: data range slicer]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a descending order to your YEAR slicer and make "**Single Select**" on from the slicer properties. This way the top most value will automatically selected when you refresh your report and for a descending order, current Year value will be on top and selected.

The date range slicer will also populated based on the selected value in the Year slicer.